Very Slow Connection with AG Listener IP in Cluster Node
We have many databases in a cluster with two nodes. Every DB has a single IP listener.
Let's say Nodes are:

X-DB01
X-DB02

And DB name is APP_DB with listener: 172.22.2.22,1433
Our observations:

Connection from a client with any cases is GOOD
X-DB01\APP_DB with both sa and AD account is GOOD
172.22.2.22,1433 with sa account is GOOD
172.22.2.22,1433 with AD account is SO SLOW

What is the problem?


172.22.2.22,1433 with AD account is SO SLOW

This will force NTLM authentication, in which the client sends data to your SQL Server, which will validate it by communicating with the domain controller.  See the flow documented here.

When using the hostname, you may be using Kerberos, which doesn't require the SQL Server to communicate with the domain controller.  See here.

So troubleshoot the SQL Server's domain controller connectivity.

And anything to make NTLM go away is a good thing. They shouldn't be using the IP address for AD accounts in the first place just for this alone ;/

They both are in same VLAN, no FW rules. I've tried with AG's "Listener DNS Name", it is also fast.
By the way the observation which resulted "SO SLOW" is result in cluster itself. Connection from a client is normal.
